# Conditioned event lower than reunion of conditioned events?

Tags: probability

Given events $A_1, A_2, B, C$ with

> $$\mathbb{P}(A_1|B)>\mathbb{P}(A_1|C)\space\text{and}\space \mathbb{P}(A_2|B)>\mathbb{P}(A_2|C).$$

Is it possible that

> $$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|B)<\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|C)? $$

I tried to find a contradiction by assuming

> $$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|B)<\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|C)$$

and I get:

> $$\mathbb{P}(A_1|B)+\mathbb{P}(A_2|B)-\mathbb{P}(A_1A_2|B)<\mathbb{P}(A_1|C)+\mathbb{P}(A_2|C)-\mathbb{P}(A_1A_2|C)$$

and then

> $$\mathbb{P}(A_1A_2|B)=\mathbb{P}(A_1A_2B)/\mathbb{P}(B).$$

I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example to show you that it is possible.

$A_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11\},$
$A_2 = \{1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12\},$ $B = \{1,2,3,20\},$ $C = \{7,8,9,10\}.$

Assume that all sample points are equally likely. Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(A_1|B) = \mathbb{P}(A_2|B) = 0.75 > 0.50 = \mathbb{P}(A_1|C) = \mathbb{P}(A_2|C).$ However, if we consider the union we get $\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|B) = 0.75 < 1 = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2|C).$ This is possible because too much of the probability from the events conditioned on B are in the intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2.$ Hope this is instructive, let me know if you want more explanation.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem!  Was an interesting question that took me a little bit to figure out how this could be possible. It does seem a bit counter-intuitive at first glance.

Comment: It is from "Introduction to Probability" - Joseph K. Blitzstein & Jessica Hwang (chapter 2).